# How to hide /wp-content/uploads/ from URL?

Tags: plugins

I have a Wordpress mulitsite and I want to hide the /wp-content/uploads/ part form URL in images and files.

The url now like this:
http://localhost/wordpress/teszt3/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/05/VCC.jpg

I want to this:
http://localhost/wordpress/teszt3/sites/3/2015/05/VCC.jpg

I try this in .htacces, but not working:

```
RewriteRule ^files$ /wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/05/VCC.jpg [L,QSA]
```

and this:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.+)$ http://localhost/wordpress/teszt3/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had you considered actually moving the folder?

WordPress allows to customize location of whole content folder or parts of it either.

According to [moving uploads folder](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder) in Codex, as simple as:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'blog/wp-content/uploads' );
```